# When calculating a field in an attribute table, how can I find one value out of many fields when every other field has a null value?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, null, for-loop, wildcard

I have 4,018 rows of data with about 50 fields. About 45 of those fields are the same variable, but the data came from different layers, so out of those 45 fields, only one has a value for the row, the rest are null. I just need the actual value in my final field. I used a string wildcard to identify the right fields. This code returns NULL for every row.

```
def n():
    import arcpy
    fields = arcpy.ListFields('Extract_fires')
    for f in fields:
        if f == 'AVGPRE*' and f is not None:
            return(f)
```

Comment: I'm using Calculate Field. I need to return the value with my function. So basically, my final field will eliminate null values and the merge all of those fields

Comment: 'f.name == 'AVGPRE*' definitely makes sense, I'll try that out, thanks. The 'is not None' should refer to the field's value for that row. Hopefully that makes sense, sorry I'm new to python

Comment: Ok nice. I would not use field calculator for this, to complicated. I would use da.UpdateCursor (which is "easier" when you get the hang of it)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try that out. I adjusted .ListFields to hold the wildcard, so it cut out that conditional in the if statement

Comment: `f.name == 'AVGPRE*' ` definitely *doesn't* make sense, because asterisk is not a permitted character in field names (alphanumeric and underscore only), so it will never evaluate True.  You can test `'AVGPRE' in f.name.upper()` to accomplish your goal.  The `None` test is useless, since it will never be False.

Comment: Hi Vince, the asterisk is a placeholder for an unknown number of characters. It's just the python representation, not part of the field name

Comment: That's not how wildcards work in Python. That comparison will *never* return True.

Comment: Thanks BERA, I'll look into it and see if I can work it out. And Vince, I'm not sure how else to use a wildcard

Comment: You should use it in listfields, for example `arcpy.Listfields(feature_class, 'AVGPRE*)` to list fields starting with AVGPRE. Wild cards does not exist in pure python (as far as i know). A python way could be `if f.name.startswith('AVGPRE')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\polygons123' #Change
field_to_hold_the_nonNonevalue = 'somefield' #Change
#List all fields starting with AVGPRE, and add the field to update last in list
fieldlist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc, 'AVGPRE*') if f.name != field_to_hold_the_nonNonevalue] + [field_to_hold_the_nonNonevalue]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #For each row in the attribute table 
        #row is now a tuple of all fields values, for example (None, None, 1, None, ... None)
        value = [val for val in row[:-1] if val is not None][0] #Pick the first (index 0) non-None value in the row
        row[-1] = value #Set the last field in fieldlist to value
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm in a class right now, but I'll try it out right after.